# Adding link to image and target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a image via js and can't seem to figure out how to add a link as well as target="_blank" to that image... here the code I am working with:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').delegate('.post-type-icon', 'click', function(){
   var url = $(this).parents('.post-content').attr('data-url');
   var newwindow = window.open('http://instagram.com?_url='+encodeURIComponent(url),'windowname','height=350,width=500');
 });
});
```

Right now with this code when you click on the icon  doesn't open to the link... not sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @jsavage980 Let me guess: `$(this).parents('.post-content').find('img')` is your image?

Comment: Don't use `.delegate()` though, it has been superseded (I quote) by `.on()` for a while.

Comment: @Krzysztof yes that is corrrect

Comment: @Cameron <div class="post-icon></div>

Comment: @Cameron here is the css as well... .post-type-icon{
  background-image: url('http://greatfutures.org/images/Instagram_logo_30px.png');
  display: block !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 14px;
}

Answer (score 2):

window.open is used for opening popup windows, try this:

```
<a href='/someurl' target='_blank'>
  <div id='yourimage'></div>
</a>
```

This way if they click on your image, its contained in an anchor tag and will cause a window to be opened in a new tab.